# JavaScript. setInterval with empty function returns 2

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have next code:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {}, 1000)
```

When I try to output `timer`, it contains "2" (number).

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/x0Iwc0ZjTI1HDFv9oxyc?p=preview

Please, explain me this behavior.

Comment: It's explained very well on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the [interval ID.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) That's a number generated by the browser that you can reference later.

The reason for this is so you can use `clearInterval` to stop looping.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  // Will only run once
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```